# Why doesn't my dataframe sum?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

```
import pandas as pd
output=pd.read_csv('output.csv',encoding='big5')

output['airplane'].sum()
```

I am attempting to sum the numbers in the dataframe, however when invoking `sum()` it just prints out the numbers I wish to sum. Why is it not summing all the numbers?

```
'5,0514,7834,3734,7925,4624,9404,8344,9045,1964,0213,9405,0515,1894,9805,0556,0595,7194,6255,4985,3305,3175,3785,6494,5514,3335,1605,3175,3175,3435,8994,6164,3145,2915,2445,2905,5055,7344,5074,1965,4815,6215,6135,6756,0035,1004,0065,5815,2963,1683,5623,8734,1104,2144,6275,3745,2025,8545,3684,5614,4245,3405,0525,0985,0945,6404,6874,3575,0355,0665,2985,1125,5954,9374,4015,2595,1505,2215,1755,9214,6694,3595,2935,2185,2695,3356,1814,9284,5755,1725,3925,8546,4215,5494,5423,7324,63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `,` to empty string by [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) and then convert to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), because `,` is thousands separator:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'airplane':['5,051','4,783','4,373']})
print (output)
  airplane
0    5,051
1    4,783
2    4,373

print (output['airplane'].sum())
5,0514,7834,373

print (output['airplane'].str.replace(',','').astype(int).sum())
14207
```

---

```
print (output['airplane'].replace(',','', regex=True).astype(int).sum())
14207
```

But you can try also add parameter `thousands` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
output=pd.read_csv('output.csv',encoding='big5', thousands=',')

print (output['airplane'].sum())
```

Comment: Bur my number contain ',' ,I can't convert it.

Comment: 0    5,051      1    4,783       2    4,373      3    4,792       4    5,462
Name: airplane, dtype: object